# Playing placeholder video while loading another - FFMPEG pipe

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently outputting some video from FFMPEG to another piece of software with a command similar to the following

```
ffmpeg -i http://example.com/video.m3u8 -f mpegts pipe:1
```

However my internet is rather slow, so the stream often times out in the external software, before it has a chance to load in FFMPEG.

Is there some way to play some sort of 'placeholder' video while waiting for the HLS stream to load? I looked into the overlay filter, however that only seems to work when both videos have loaded, making it unsuitable.

Comment: What do you mean by "the stream often times out"? When your Internet is slow, does the `ffmpeg` process die? Or does it simply take too long for the output pipe to output data so that your program dies waiting for it?

Comment: It takes too long for the output pipe to output data, so the program dies waiting for it.